# positive integer solutions of $y=\frac{5x}{3x-5}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Any ideas on how to approach that problem besides brute-force?

One solution is (x,y)=(2,10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide $5x$ by $3x-5$ to get

$3y=5+\frac{25}{3x-5}$

For y to be an integer $3x-5$ must divide $25$ hence

$3x-5=\pm1,\pm5,\pm25$

Solve to get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the equation as $3xy-5y-5x=0$ and then as $9xy-15x-15y=0$ and then as $(3x-5)(3y-5)=25$. (We were completing a rectangle.)
So we are looking for pairs $(u,v)$ of integers such that $u$ has remainder $1$ on division by $3$ and $uv=25$.